# MySQL variable get NULL from SUM()

Tags: mysql, variables, integer, sum

I have this MySQL statement:

```
SELECT  @my_sum := SUM(delibera.particolari_prodotti),
@my_sum_copy := @my_sum + 1
FROM delibera
```

I can't understand the reason why @my_sum has a numeric value but @my_sum_copy is NULL.

I've tried also this:

```
SELECT  @my_sum := SUM(delibera.particolari_prodotti),
@my_sum_copy := CONVERT(@my_sum, UNSIGNED) + 1
FROM delibera
```

... and this:

```
SELECT  @my_sum := CONVERT(SUM(delibera.particolari_prodotti), UNSIGNED),
@my_sum_copy := @my_sum + 1
FROM delibera
```

but it's the same.

How can I get that @my_sum_copy has a valid numeric value?

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE:
With the code

```
SELECT
    @`my_sum`,
    @`my_sum_copy` := @`my_sum` + 1
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            @`my_sum` := SUM(`particolari_prodotti`)
        FROM
        `delibera`,
            (SELECT
                @`my_sum` := NULL,
                @`my_sum_copy` := NULL
            ) `inner_der` 
        ) `outer_der`;
```

I finally have a value for @my_sum_copy.

But now @my_sum in set to [BLOB - 8 B].

Comment: Accorfding to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), the order of evaluation of these expressions is undefined. Which in this case means `@my_sum := ...` is evaluated after `@my_sum_copy :=...`. You should probably find a more robust way to do what you need.

Comment: @Vatev: undefined, but for the past long while, mysql's evaluted/calculated stuff left->right. while not a guarantee of future behavior, it's at least semi-reliable behavior.

Comment: Yes, and it's still behaving semi-reliably: it doesn't always do what you expect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation:

> [9.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)
>
> ...
>
> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement.
>
> ...
>
> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed.
>
> ...
>
> ..., the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.
>
> ...

One option that can be useful is to use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT
  @`my_sum`,
  @`my_sum_copy` := @`my_sum` + 1
FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      @`my_sum` := SUM(`particolari_prodotti`)
    FROM
      `delibera`,
      (SELECT
         @`my_sum` := NULL,
         @`my_sum_copy` := NULL
      ) `inner_der` 
  ) `outer_der`;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed1da/2)</kbd>